# Is there a way in delphi (Pascal object) to make a for each like in java?

Tags: java, arrays, delphi, object, for-loop

i started today learning delphi.
i m wondering if there is a way to make a delphi code like mine on java using the for each with array of objects.
there is my java code:

```
     class test {
        public static void main(String[] args){

              String[] names={"ali","samad","kamel","djamel","mustapha"};

              for(String name:names){
                      System.out.println("user:"+name);
                  }
          }
       }
```

thanks.

Comment: As a side note: iterating arrays and collections is too steep for the first day.

Comment: i m used for java programming for 2 years and all i need is to know how to do what i used to in java on delphi.@FreeConsulting

Comment: That is, need more learning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`for..in`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_statements) loop, like so

```
const
  names : array [0..4] of string  = ('ali','samad','kamel','djamel','mustapha');
var
 s : string;
begin
  try
    for s in names do
     Writeln(s);

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: can i use this model what ever the type of object in the array ? like array of persons or teachers ??

Comment: Yes, you can use this in Dynamic arrays and Static arrays,

Comment: You guys forget to mention that for in loop is only supported in Delphi 2005 and newer. So if OP has older version of delphi he won't be able to use it.

Comment: @SilverWarior, I don't want to come across rude but it really pains me whenever I see warnings like "Careful! Your Delphi needs to be less than a decade old to use this". Ever heard somebody, within the last six or eight years, warn you "You should be aware that those fancy generics need at least Java JDK 1.5"?

Comment: @SilverWarior, Forgetting to mention that users *more* than 10 years behind in technology might not have the *latest* technology is not as much "forgetting" than avoiding to state the obvious. ;-)

Comment: Also, a guy still using Delphi older than 2005 should probably know a bit about the language by now.

Comment: Forgot to mention that `for .. in` also works for lists and dictionaries using Generics in modern Delphis.

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb `for..in` is natively supported for many of the appropriate types. And, if you need it for a custom container object, you can write your own enumerator. One of this site's contributors (gabr) has written a nice series of articles on this: http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2007/03/fun-with-enumerators-part-1.html